# Kubernetes nfs define path in claim

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create common persistence volume with nfs.

PV(nfs):

```
common-data-pv       1500Gi       RWO           Retain
192.168.0.24 /home/common-data-pv
```

I want a claim or pod(mount the claim) subscribed common-data-pv can define path example :

```
/home/common-data-pv/www-site-1(50GI)
/home/common-data-pv/www-site-2(50GI)
```

But i not found in documentation how i can define this.

My actual conf for pv :

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: common-data-pv
  labels:
    type: common
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1500Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.122.1
    path: "/home/pv/common-data-pv"



kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: common-data-pvc
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: common
```

Example use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nfs-web-1
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    role: web-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: web-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
            # name must match the volume name below
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: common-data-pvc

apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nfs-web-2
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    role: web-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: web-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
            # name must match the volume name below
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: common-data-pvc
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the claim you just need to add a volumeMounts section and volumes to your manifest. Here's an example replication controller for nginx that would use your claim. Note the very last line that uses the same PVC name.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nfs-web
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    role: web-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: web-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
            # name must match the volume name below
            - name: nfs
              mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: common-data-pvc
```

More examples can be found in the kubernetes repo [under examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/volumes/nfs)

Comment: Yes i know ;-) . So imagine you create a new RC with name nfs-web-2 with same PVC or PV all file is registered in same directory (so you can have conflict). I edit my question with a example.

Comment: You can't reuse the same claim on different RCs/Deployments. You would need to use sub-directories per RC and claim those. To do this in an automated fashion you should use an auto-provisioner that can create the resources for you. Here is a nfs-provisioner that is being adopted as a kubernetes incubator project https://github.com/wongma7/nfs-provisioner Here's it's future home https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/nfs-provisioner